# Proof of k-th Difference operator with sequence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Difference_operator_and_difference_equations

I know that
$$
\Delta^k a_n = \sum_{t=0}^{k} (-1)^t \binom{k}{t}a_{n+k-t}.
$$

But I don't know how to prove that
$$ 
a_{n+k} = a_{n} + \binom{k}{1} \Delta a_n 
+ \cdots + \binom{k}{k} \Delta^{k}(a_n).
$$
How to prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a sequence $a_n$, define the operator $S$ by
$$
Sa_n=a_{n+1}\tag1
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta^ka_n
&=(S-1)^ka_n\tag{2a}\\[9pt]
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}S^{k-j}a_n\tag{2b}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}a_{n+k-j}\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ $\Delta=S-1$
$\text{(2b):}$ Binomial Theorem
$\text{(2c):}$ apply $(1)$

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\Delta^ka_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{m}{k}\binom{k}{j}a_{n+k-j}\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{m}{k}\binom{k}{j}a_{n+j}\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=j}^m(-1)^{k-j}\binom{m}{j}\binom{m-j}{k-j}a_{n+j}\tag{3c}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}[j=m]a_{n+j}\tag{3d}\\[6pt]
&=a_{n+m}\tag{3e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ apply $(2)$
$\text{(3b):}$ substitute $j\mapsto k-j$
$\text{(3c):}$ $\binom{m}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{m}{j}\binom{m-j}{k-j}$ (expand into ratios of factorials)
$\text{(3d):}$ $\sum\limits_{k=j}^m(-1)^{k-j}\binom{m-j}{k-j}=[j=m]$ ([Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket))
$\text{(3e):}$ evaluate the sum

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is perhaps a simpler solution. Let $L$ be the left shift operator; given a sequence $a$, $La$ is a new sequence, for which $(La)_n=a_{n+1}$.

Note that $L=\Delta+1$, as operators.
This implies the following operator equation:
$$
L^k=(\Delta+1)^k=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki \Delta^i\tag1
$$
Applying the operators on both sides of $(1)$ to the sequence $a$, and examining the $n^\text{th}$ element, the result is exactly what you want:
$$
(L^ka)_n=a_{n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom ki (\Delta^i a)_n,
$$
You can prove by induction on $k$ that $(L^ka)_n=a_{n+k}$; intuitively, the $k$-fold application of the shift-by-one operator is a shift-by-$k$ operator.